# Run SQL query from a .sql file using python

Tags: python, sql

I want to execute one SQL query from a .sql file using python. The query is large enough that's why i put it in one file (say run_query.sql).
I am able to read the query and execute it, but if i want to change the query based on my python parameters is there any better way i can edit the sql file dynamically?
For example i want to edit the sql file so the content in it will produce the below query:

```
SELECT name, age FROM biodata WHERE name IN ('SAM','JOY','JHON') AND palce='BLACKTOWN'
```

So what i want a python function will take arguments like below:

```
def my_func(['SAM','JOY','JHON'], 'BLACKTOWN'):
    #do stuffs so that the sql query
    #in the file will modify  
    # then execute the query
```

Based on the above arguments passed the query will fill and then i can execute the complete query.

Note: In reality the query is large and i have to change it in so many places so normal string operations are confusing. So any other choices.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

> Definition: cursor.execute(self, query, args=None)
>
> query -- string, query to execute on server
>
> args -- optional sequence or mapping, parameters to use with query.

```
namelist =['SAM','JOY','JHON']
palce ='BLACKTOWN'
query= 'SELECT name, age FROM biodata WHERE name IN (%s) AND palce=%s'  
names= ', '.join(names for unused in namelist)
cursor.execute(query,names, palce)
```

Comment: This is a solution, but what if 1) the same parameter appear in the sql query multiple times? For now, the execute code replace the parameters by their relative position, which may not be enough when the parameters appear many times. 2) what about non-string parameters? 3) Is there API or packages that can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is use placeholders in the saved query and replace them with your variables.
For example, you would store :

`SELECT name, age FROM biodata WHERE name IN ('name1','name2','name3') AND palce='place1'`

And in python,

`query.replace('name1', "SAM")`